# Which device is using this logical volume?

Tags: rhel, lvm

I'm trying to remove an LVM logical volume, which I believe is not currently in use.

However, when I attempted to remove it, I get an error:

```
# lvremove /dev/vg_service1/lv_home 
  Logical volume vg_service1/lv_home is used by another device.
```

It's definitely not mounted, as this returns nothing:

```
# mount | grep lv_home
```

Is there any way to tell what is using this logical volume?

Comment: `mount | grep …` queries `/etc/mtab`, and can be unreliable in odd circumstances (filesystem mounted while the root filesystem was read-only, or from within a chroot). Double-check with `grep lv_home /proc/mounts` (`/proc/mounts` gives a direct view to the kernel, if you don't do it from a virtual environment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the logical volume was itself part of a volume group. It didn't show up in /proc/mounts or in the output of lsof. The only way I was able to discover this was through the "pvdisplay" command, where it appeared as a physical volume:

```
# pvdisplay 

...

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vg_service1/lv_home
  VG Name               nova-volumes
  PV Size               179.91 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  ...
```

Comment: After `pvdisplay`, How to release it?

Comment: @shgnInc: the LV «IS» a PV of other VG.  Inception style.

Answer (score 5):

Use lsof(8):

```
# lsof /dev/vg_service1/lv_home
```

I don't have access to a Linux box at this very moment to verify its output, but here's what it looks like on my Mac:

```
# lsof /dev/disk1 | head
COMMAND    PID           USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
launchd      1           root  cwd    DIR   14,4      1564       2 /
launchd      1           root  txt    REG   14,4    415248 7402611 /sbin/launchd
launchd      1           root  txt    REG   14,4     59504 7399166 /usr/lib/libauditd.0.dylib
launchd      1           root  txt    REG   14,4    599232 7402371 /usr/lib/dyld
launchd      1           root  txt    REG   14,4 289054720 8865364 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
launchd      1           root   20r   DIR   14,4       170 7402529 /private/var/tmp
launchd      1           root   24r   REG   14,4         0 9885226 /private/var/run/socketfilterfw.launchd
launchd      1           root   25r   DIR   14,4      2040 7393527 /private/var/db
```

You should see something similar on your system.

Answer (score 1):

there is yet another obscure reason why your LVM snapshot may be busy

when running `grub-update`, it will use `grub-mount` to mount devices and check if they contain a O.S. and possibly add them to the boot menu; but then `grub-update` will sometimes fail to unmount them, and in this case it will be impossible to remove the snapshot.

Note that `grub-update` will be ran automatically when a new kernel is installed, and this may happen because of an automatic security update.

The best option so far is to add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`
to `/etc/default/grub` so that `grub-update` will not mount anything. I recommend it in any case.

Coming back to the original question: if you cannot unmount your snapshot, try `umount /var/lib/os-prober/mount/`

Note that, when/if the snapshot is completely full, the snapshot will be invalid, and the above command may fail, in this case your only chance will be a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the same problem. After some searching, someone talk about the `nfs` service which for file sharing.

so in This case just need to restart the `nfs` service and then try to remove the logical volume disk:

```
service nfs-kernel-server restart
lvremove -f /dev/vg_service1/lv_home
```