# How to stop update-grub from scanning all drives?

Tags: debian, grub

Every time `update-grub` is run all hard drives are scanned. Each drives that is in standby state will spin up to go idle. This is a waste of energy. We use update-grub version 1.98:

```
# update-grub -v
grub-mkconfig (GRUB) 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1
```

*Regression*

1. There is a `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` option in the `/etc/default/grub` file. But that seems to only work from version 2 and up. At least it doesn't stop scanning all drives in our version 1.98.
2. There is a `/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen` script that might be run as a part of update-grub. After removing execute rights for all users with `chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen` all drives do still spin up.

How to stop `update-grub` from scanning each and every hard drive?

Comment: It's just a shell script... Modify it? It should only run after kernel updates, which doesn't occur very often.

Comment: One of the script lines executes `/usr/sbin/grub-probe --target=device /`. That command also causes all drives to spin up. The `/usr/sbin/grub-probe` is not a shell script.

Comment: How often are you running `update-grub`?  This should only happen when you install a new kernel, so who cares?

Comment: I know, that entire picojoule it uses is such a waste - if you ran update-grub 24/7 for a month on 1000 computers with 3 HDDs each, it might add a cent or two to your electric bill.

Comment: @psusi There can be other reasons why one wants os-prober not to touch a device, e.g. dd'ing an filesystem image file to a device, it could cause damage to mount the device while the copy is not complete.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In file **/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober** the line

```
OSPROBED="`os-prober | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
```

makes all drives spin (standby -> idle). [Os-prober](http://joeyh.name/code/os-prober/) is a utility to find Linux installations at drives other then your boot drive. It is the `os-prober` that needs to be disabled.

1. One way is to **remove the package**: `apt-get --purge remove os-prober`.
2. Another way is to **remove executable rights for os-prober**. First find the location of os-prober using `$ which os-prober`. Output might look like: `/usr/bin/os-prober`. The remove the executable rights for all users for that file: `# chmod a-x /usr/bin/os-prober`
3. Another way is to **remove executable rights for 30_os-prober**. Find the location of 30_os-prober using `$ locate /30_os-prober`. Output might look like: `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`. The remove the executable rights for all users for that file: `# chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
4. Yet another way is to **skip the execution** of `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`. For example by making the `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` option work in our grub version 1.98. This can be done by inserting in file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` the code below the line `set -e`:

...

```
if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER}" = "xtrue" ]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: #4 - GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true works as expected on GRUB 2.02/Buster/Debian 10.  It was scanning 22 of my iscsi drives across all the VM's hosted on this machine!  Neither fast nor useful!

Answer (score 7):

For those wondering if it's really worth the effort, yes it is. Perhaps not for energy saving but today I encountered a problem with update-grub as it wanted to probe for both /dev/sda (my harddisk) and /dev/sdc (a USB-stick). Without the latter inserted into my laptop, update-grub would hang, even though there is actually no OS on my USB-stick installed nor did I ever boot from this stick. As the USB-stick recently broke, I needed a way for update-grub to continue (alive) without it. Fortuately, `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` just did the trick. :)

Comment: I had the inverse problem: update-grub failing if an USB stick was present. The USB stick was a bit unusual, since it has Easy2Boot installed. But since this was on a kiosk with the update-grub command being issued from a script placed on that very USB stick, this solution was very welcome.

Comment: another problem is if you use LVM and use snapshots... grub will mount the snapshot and add them to the boot menu, but then it will sometimes fail to unmount them, and it will be impossible to remove the snapshot , so when/if the snapshot is compltetely full, your only change will be a reboot

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628160/121890

Answer (score 3):

(Is this really worth the time and effort to fix?)

As you mentioned, the probing is probably happening when `grub-mkconfig` calls `grub-probe`.  You could modify `grub-mkconfig` by simply hardcoding the result of the `grub-probe` calls.  It is used to fill `GRUB_DEVICE`, `GRUB_DEVICE_UUID`, `GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT`, `GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT_UUID`, and `GRUB_FS`.

Answer (score 2):

See [my solution here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347466/debian-new-error-message-upgrading-kernel-to-4-9-reload-ioctl-error/475627#475627) to selectively disable which partitions are checked by `os-prober` with a small `patch`.

The configuration of `GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="UUID@device_path"` in `/etc/default/grub`:

- reduces the numbers of devices in `${OSPROBED}` used by `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
- which stops the check with `${grub_probe} --target=fs_uuid --device`

Comment: This works now (Ubuntu 21.10) without patch. Just make the skip list in `/etc/default/grub` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found another way to accomplish this that doesn't involve making changes to the scripts. in `/etc/grub.d/` I renamed the file `30_os-prober` to `.30_os-prober` (start with a period) and it is skipped during the update even though it shows in the same place in `ls` if you use `-a`.