# Is os-prober a security risk?

Tags: debian, security, grub

I'm conducting a security audit and came across this utility running on my Debian system. (Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1)

It strikes me that a piece of software like this should not be installed on a secure server.  I don't know exactly what it does when it finds any installed OSs.
Should I be disabling os-prober, and how do I do that?
OR
Should I be disabling grub, and how do I do that?

Comment: The latest DISA STIGs (OpenSCAP)  are silent on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

`os-prober` is there to detect other operating systems. If you do not need that functionality, you can disable it; I have done that in all my Debian VMs after hitting some hiccup in testing.

You add to `/etc/default/grub` the line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

And then, the commands `dpkg-reconfigure` linux-image-xxxxx and `update-grub` no longer will use `os-prober`.

Another alternative is to uninstall `os-prober`.

```
dpkg --purge os-prober
```

As [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) points out, "The package itself is only recommended (by [grub-common](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/grub-common)), so the package manager will allow you to remove it."

Or just to be on the safe side, for it not to be used anymore, do both actions.

From this [link](https://joeyh.name/code/os-prober/)

> os-prober is a spinoff of debian-installer. One of the installer's
> features is that it can probe disks on the system for other operating
> systems, and add them to the boot loader, so that installing Debian
> doesn't make your other installed OS hard to boot.

see [Debian: New error message upgrading kernel (to 4.9) - reload ioctl error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347466/debian-new-error-message-upgrading-kernel-to-4-9-reload-ioctl-error)

Summing it up: it is a good idea to disable os-prober for linux servers; furthermore it is also conducive to the (security) philosophy of Unix, of keeping it simple and installing the less amount of services/software.

While in theory you could also manage to go without grub I would not trade the standard way, convenience, flexibility of booting and debugging capabilities it offers, for other scenarios. See [LILO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_(boot_loader))/ELILO; and [u-boot-tools](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/WebHome) for an alternative, at least in some architectures.

As for grub security, I would worry more of [adding a password](http://www.elinuxbook.com/how-to-protect-grub2-bootloader-with-password-in-linux/) to it.

Comment: GRUB2 is an abomination forced upon the Linux community.  There is nothing simple about it - just look at the number of shell scripts, executives, and configuration files it installs.   Suffers from a major architectural flaw - If you have multiple Linux installations, each Linux installation keeps its own notion of GRUB configuration state.

Comment: @fpmurphy What are you using? I am doing a lateral move to Free or OpenBSD; some links about Grub?

Answer (score -2):

`os-prober` is used by `GRUB` to configure GRUB startup options such as menu stanzas.

If you boot your system using `EFI STUB`, `coreboot`, or some other non-GRUB mechanism (there are many!) , you certainly can disable/remove GRUB and os-prober.

If you boot your system using GRUB (which is the default boot mechanism), do not disable/remove anything associated with GRUB including os-prober or you can end up not being able to boot into other OSes on a multi-OS platform.

Comment: Removing `os-prober` won’t result in an unbootable system; at worst it will result in other OSs no longer being listed in the Grub boot menu.

Comment: @StephenKitt. GRUB is intended to be a multiboot loader.  Many users regard a system as unbootable when they cannot boot into one of the installed OSes they wish to boot into.

Comment: I don’t claim to speak for “many users”, but I consider that a system that can boot something useful without an external recovery CD or USB key is bootable. Especially in this case — removing `os-prover` would still allow the user to boot the system needed to restore access to the other OSs (by re-installing `os-prober`; admittedly that may not be obvious since the reboot might occur a long time after the removal).